# Catch Statement Problems Battleships game

Tags: java, exception

I am having problems with Catch statements as I am very new to them and in the process of learning them. 
The program I am creating takes input from the user to place a ship on a 10x10 grid using x and y co-ords and a Boolean true/false to place them upwards or sideways. The exceptions are been caught when a player enters a number too high/too low or enters the ship out of the grid, I have used a while statement to try loop this around but the program is not looping back on itself. If anyone with any more experience on these statements could take a look and point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

```
do {
    try {

        boolean updown = sc.nextBoolean();
        if (updown == true) {
            grid[x][y] = 'S';
            grid[x + 1][y] = 'S';
            grid[x + 2][y] = 'S';
            grid[x + 3][y] = 'S';
            drawGrid(grid);
        } else if (updown == false) {
            grid[x][y] = 'S';
            grid[x][y + 1] = 'S';
            grid[x][y + 2] = 'S';
            grid[x][y + 3] = 'S';
            drawGrid(grid);
            retry = 2;
        }

    } catch (InputMismatchException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        sc.next();
        System.out.println("Incorrect input please try again!"); 
    }

} while (retry == 2);
```

Comment: What does 'having no luck' mean? What, exactly, isn't working? By the way, it's a bad practice to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should be using guard `if` statements.

Comment: sorry I will edit my question, it catches the errors and I get no error in console but the program keeps going and will not allow me to re input the values if the user goes wrong

Comment: You are not reading x,y in the loop, so the error cannot be fixed. You did not provide definition of the scanner, so I can only asume that sc.next() will just eat next line and the sc.nextBoolean will just always fail

Comment: In your loop, you never set `retry` to anything other than `2`. You haven't shown how it is initialised, but if it is initialised to `2`, your loop will be infinite. If it is not, your loop will either be infinite (if `updown == false`) or will only execute once.